# Timezone lookup

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, csv, timezone

I have a file that contains the following in a csv file;
country,region,city,postalCode,metroCode,areaCode

I need to find the time zone for the entries.

I have seen olson database and geonames, i was lost with olson database. couldnt find anything useful.

is there any web site i can access the time zone information based on country, region, city?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to query this.

http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at this [here](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm)...the timezone database is in the public domain.

Comment: that s olson database, if you look at it, it s a total mess, i couldnt find anything useful.

Comment: @user177883: Sounds like you're looking to determine what timezone a user is in based on their address, whereas the Olson database tells you the rules which determine the local time in that timezone. It does list by city, but that's really just a convenient set of labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you can geocode your address to a latitude/longitude pair, you can give those coordinates plus a datetime to [DRT Engine](http://drtengine.com/pages/geo_get_timezone) and get back a timezone offset.